# Help with using a tunnel diode in LTspice

Tags: diodes, ltspice

I want to use a tunnel diode to implement a simple van der pol oscillator 
circuit. So far I found a SPICE code for 1N4393 from this [reference](http://www.eng.auburn.edu/~wilambm/pap/1997/SBook/5_ELE.PDF).

Is it possible to simulate 1N4393 to convert and use the following SPICE code for LTspice?:

```
* JFET n-type, analog switch; 40V 50 mA, low Ron resistance
.MODEL 1N4393 NJF (VTO=-1.50 BETA=4m LAMBDA=.035 RD=14 RS=15 IS=2E-15
+ CGS=7p CGD=9p KF=1.5E-16
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the same model statements/parameters are used.

Comment: @Andyaka In  LTspice diode models are given as follows: .model DA227Y D(Is=936.8p N=1.721 Rs=1.02 Ikf=28.9 Cjo=1.793p M=189.9m Vj=865.3m Isr=2.051n Nr=2.4 Bv=80 tt=37n Iave=0.1 Vpk=80 mfg=Rohm type=Switching) But the code in question is different I tried to copy paste it but didnt see such diode in LTspice. Maybe a modification is required. Waiting for some LTspice wizards save me.

Comment: Chua et al., 1985, DOI: 10.1109/TCS.1985.1085599

Comment: Found this open access thing on [Esaki diode modeling](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/apec/2011/830182/). I don't consider it anywhere near as interesting as the seminal paper I mentioned earlier. But it's available on the web. So that is its good point.

Answer (score 1):

If you can tolerate a cheap solution then use a diode and a VCSW with negative hysteresis. There's not much guarantee you'll get the exact same slopes as with a tunel diode but, given your way of posing the problem:

> I want to use a tunnel diode to implement *a simple van der pol oscillator* circuit. [emphasis mine]

it looks like you can stomach such shortcomings. With that in mind here's a solution that works by adding an aritifial negative slope in the diode's I-V characteristic (top circuit, blue trace), and how it can cause oscillations (bottom circuit, red trace):

[image: cheap SPICE tunnel diode]

Tune the characteristics for both the diode's and the VCSW's `.MODEL`s. With enough care, you might even make a chaotic circuit.

---

[edit]

The level 1 VCSW seems to have some unwanted discontinuities, which is what cause the sharp waveform for the oscillations. Using the tanh() smoothing of level=2 makes the response much better behaved, though a bit finicky when trying to match the curve. However, the result is now this (the middle plot is a zoomed-in version of the bottom plot, to show the smooth waveform):

[image: tunnel diode with level=2 VCSW]

Answer (score 0):

JFET; TRANSISTOR. Anyhow, I tried the model as a Diode and realized it cannot function in open circuits or 2 separated by a capacitor. And at high resistance, parallel and series components in reference to their usage generate low current.

That must mean something other than what I believe or what I believe; They can be used in two diodes and one diode open circuits, or since it's a TRANSISTOR model, if used with a Diode it is the wrong model and some sort of short circuit shutoff occurs due to a potential Collector and Base interaction. SWB.

[image]